# Install Gnome without Apt-get

Tags: gnome, 13.10

I have a server which is not connected (nor do I want to connect it) to my network. I am trying to find out how I can install Gnome without using apt-get, however I cannot find the files for gnome anywhere.

I have googled and researched this, but I still have not had any luck finding the answer. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Its Ubuntu 13.10 Server x64.

Comment: Why would you want gnome on a server ? At any rate, if you do not want to use apt-get , you would need to download and compile all of gnome and all of the dependencies (X) manually. I suggest you see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Installing_packages_without_an_Internet_connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all details on ubuntu wiki about [how to prepare packages to install offline with aptitude.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Use_apt-offline)

**Use apt-offline :**

apt-offline allows you to easily upgrade or install new packages on your offline PC, by using another online PC.

`sudo apt-get install apt-offline`

Upgrading

1. On the offline PC:

   `sudo apt-offline set /tmp/apt-offline.sig`
2. On the online PC:

   `sudo apt-offline get C:\apt-offline.sig --bug-reports --threads 5`
3. On the offline PC:

   `sudo apt-offline install /media/USB/apt-offline.zip`

Installing

1. On the offline PC:

   `sudo apt-offline set abuse-offline.sig --install-packages abuse --src-build-dep --install-src-packages abuse`
2. On the online PC:

   `sudo apt-offline get abuse-offline.sig --no-checksum --bundle abuse-offline.zip`
3. On the offline PC:

   `sudo apt-offline install /media/USB/abuse-offline.zip`

More info :

1. [apt-offline homepage](http://apt-offline.alioth.debian.org/)
2. [apt-offline upgrade howto](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT)
3. [apt-offline install howto](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10198406&postcount=5)